# HTTPS & HTTP domain confusion

Tags: http, https, dns, hosting, plesk

This issue has been plaguing me for days and I cannot seem to solve it.

I recently wanted to help out a friend with their 'Let's Encrypt' issues, as the software was throwing out a 404 error for a certain file it needed. After some digging I discovered some DNS inconsistencies between which domain linked to what IP.
Today I noticed that something really weird is going on. The set up looks like this:

```
https://websitename.com/ - 1st version of the website - Secure
https://www.websitename.com/ - 2nd version of the website - Not Secure
http://websitename.com/ - 1st version of the website - Not Secure
http://www.websitename.com/ - 3rd version of the website - Not Secure
```

I am not sure how something like this can even happen. By version of a website I mean an actual fully hosted website on a different IP.

I have not touched any of the htaccess files yet. I have checked all of the DNS settings for all of the given IPs but nothing seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the "www" CNAME record and the A record for the site are pointing to two different locations.

## Problem

Just took a look at your DNS records. You have a record: 
`WWW record www.fish4parts.com A records are: www.fish4parts.com. A 91.121.225.216 [TTL=3600]`

This record exists at ui-dns.com, which is separate from your fish4parts.com A Record.

## Solution

If you cannot see the records on both of those NameServers (NS) you should give their support desk a call and ask them to remove the www A record from the ui-dns.com name server. If they are unresponsive you can always switch DNS providers at your domain. I use O365 for our domains, but previously used [AWS Route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/). The AWS product is super easy to use and very cheap.

Comment: Below are all of the DNS settings:

ns1.fish4parts.com. A 77.68.86.19
webmail.fish4parts.com. A 77.68.86.19
fish4parts.com. NS ns1.fish4parts.com.
fish4parts.com. TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +a:localhost.localdomain -all
fish4parts.com. NS ns2.fish4parts.com.
mail.fish4parts.com. A 77.68.86.19
ipv4.fish4parts.com. A 77.68.86.19
fish4parts.com. A 77.68.86.19
fish4parts.com. MX (10) mail.fish4parts.com.
ftp.fish4parts.com. CNAME fish4parts.com.
_dmarc.fish4parts.com. TXT v=DMARC1; p=none
ns2.fish4parts.com. A 77.68.86.19
www.fish4parts.com. CNAME fish4parts.com.

Comment: Just took a look at your DNS records. You have a record:
`WWW record www.fish4parts.com A records are: 

www.fish4parts.com. A 91.121.225.216 [TTL=3600]`

This record exists at ui-dns.com, which is separate from your fish4parts.com A Record.

If you cannot see the records on both of those NameServers (NS) you should give their support desk a call and ask them to remove the www A record from the ui-dns.com name server.

If they are unresponsive you can always switch DNS providers at your domain registrar.